# Any better condition checking?

Tags: jquery

I have one functionality where I am hiding few rows of a table on pageload.After that on click of a span, I am calling the toggle() to dispaly and hide rows in alternate click.Now I need to do some additional work after the toogle(), for that I am doing one check

```
            $myRows.toggle();

            if ($myRows.css('display') === 'none') {
               //my code
            }
            else {
                     //mycode
                   }
```

Now can I have some better checking instead of   **if ($myRows.css('display') === 'none')**, its working fine, but can I go for any better condition checking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if ($myRows.is(':hidden')) ...
```